# Is that possible to set gradient on text color?

Tags: html, colors, css, gradient, firefox3.6

Firefox 3.6 allows to set [gradient on backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient#section_4).

Is that possible to set gradient on the text color as well ?

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/MP4gZ/):

HTML:

```
<span>Hello</span>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, white);
}
span {
    font-size: 13em;
    color: #222;
}
```

I would like to "replace" `#222` with `-moz-linear-gradient(left, white, blue);`, for example.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Why not just try it and see if it works?

Comment: Believe me that I tried before I wrote this question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need this for a small amount of text (like a heading), you should be able to achieve the effect in Safari/Chrome using `-webkit-background-clip: text` and `-webkit-gradient`. (Firefox doesn’t support this yet.)

[This demo doesn’t use gradients, but it should explain `background-clip: text`](http://webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/)

Answer (score 0):

`h1 {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 70pt;
        margin-top: 0;
    }`

```
h1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffcc33; /* or rgb/a */
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
}
//css to enter the content on page after render - optional
h1:after {
    content : 'Hello World';
    color: #d6d6d6;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}
```

Comment: I tried to put your code in my example above, but it doesn't work. Could you please post a working example ?

Comment: This doesn't make the text gradient.